# Car makes rattling sound after shifting gears?

Tags: toyota, noise, alternator, camry, gears

Recently after I got my alternator and battery replaced,  I noticed that after a night or two whenever I tried to start my car (after engine turned on), I heard a rattling sound if i started shifting gear from park to either reverse or drive. The noise went away if I proceeded to hit the gas. I hear no noise after I started driving.

What could be the cause of this? Would it be something that the mechanic screwed up on?

My car is Toyota Camry 2006

Comment: Year, make, and model of car?  Most alternators are pretty easy to get to, so the mechanic wouldn't normally have to mess with very much (less stuff for them to get wrong).

Comment: There is no way for us to know without more information or seeing the car. If the noise was not there before the work was done, it is possible the mechanic left something loose or unattached. Take it back and have them inspect their work.